# Rails: randomly pick a image as background image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm making a page with a background image, and I want to make the background image changes automatically.
The images have been saved in directory already.

One possible solution would be set up a BackgroundImage class, and make those images record in the database, so  `@backgroundimage = BackgroundImage.all.shuffle.first`, and then use it in view page like `img_tag @backgroundimage`

Another approach would be something like `<img src='backgroundimages/image#{@random-number}>`? I think this is possible if I name those images like `image1,image2`,and get a random number each time in the controller. But it requires renaming images by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the images in one Folder then read all filenames and return a random image name so you whouldnt need a naming schema or a database backed model. Like this:

```
def random_image
  blacklist = [".", ".."]
  file_names = Dir.glob("/path/to/images/*")
  blacklist.each do |blacklsited|
    file_names.delete(blacklisted)
  end
  "/webserver/path/to/images/{files.shuffle.first}"
end
```

So in the view you could call the helper method `random_image`.

Comment: So I have to remove the '.' and '..' in file_names?

Comment: That blacklist stuff is not necessary. `.` and `..` are [excluded by default](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob).

Comment: I think it depends on the rails version I had some trouble with it but Im not really sure if that affects to the glob method too...

Comment: `Dir.glob` is Ruby and doesn't have anything to do with Rails. In 1.9.3 and 2.0 you don't have to use blacklist like that. You should not be using any older version than 1.9.3 IMO. Apart from that, this is obviously the most sane method of randomly selecting a background image.

Comment: It is now working in development mode, I use `file_names = Dir.entries('public/background')` and it still need to delete ` [".", ".."]`. And I make it return "background/#{file_names.shuffle.first}"

Comment: @Mischa of cause your right its about the ruby version, was a typing error^^

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
BackgroundImage.order("RAND()").limit(1)
```

depending on your database it could be ‘RANDOM()’ or something similar

it generates sql query like this

```
SELECT "background_images".* FROM "background_images" ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: So `rand().limit()` is faster than`all.shuffle.first()`?

Comment: @cqcn1991 yes off-course, it is transformed into into sql query to get on one record, in your case first you fetch all record, shuffle them and selects one of it with shuffle method.